# Transaction (Process ID 461) was deadlocked

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-deadlocks

I run a script which creates Database, Procedures and Tables in that database; I got following error message:

```
Msg 1205, Level 13, State 51, Line 1
Transaction (Process ID 461) was deadlocked on lock resources with another 
 process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
```

And after that error message, there are messages like below:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

I can't see any DB created in sql server.But when I fire select statement of one of the table of that database, I get data of that table.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/09/09/deadlock-troubleshooting_2c00_-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But, I recommend you to **restart your sql server**.

So, it will again check your scripts and give you a true result whether your database have that table or not

Comment: Thanks. it worked. The strange thing was DB was not created. I don't know why it was showing records of that table previously. I run scripts again and I can now see the database now.